# What is needed to make angular meteor helpers work?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

this is my first question in stackoverflow!

I have troubles with angular-meteor helpers, i can't get them to work.

I defined this helper block inside my controller.

```
this.helpers({
    testers: () => { return Testers.find() }
});
```

I created the "Testers" collection.

```
Testers = new Mongo.Collection("testers");
```

Also made the publication and subscription with:

```
$reactive(this).attach($scope);
this.subscribe('testers');
```

Inside the browser's console i already have access to "Testers" collection and it is reactively updating with Mongo database, i checked that already.

For testing purposes i placed inside the "testers" helper function a console.log and it is indeed getting executed but i dont know why it is not creating the "$scope.testers" variable.

I am using ui-router so i assigned the controller with:

```
.state('user.index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'client/user/cheques/list.html',
    controller: 'testCtrl',
})
```

I placed a regular variable inside the scope and it gets to the view without trouble as always but i can't get the helper variables.

Does my controller in router assignation matter? Im missing something? 
using: angular 1.3.7, angular-meteor 1.3.6

Answer (score 0):

It will create this.testers. you should use controllerAs in your router ,and then use vm.testers (or your other controller as name)

Comment: There's no way to avoid using the "controllerAs"?